# Converting Erlang record to binary

Tags: erlang

I have a method for which I need to pass a record as a binary. I tried list_to_binary/1 both by passing the record itself in and converting the record to a list first then passing it in. However, I get a bagarg error with either options. Not sure what I'm missing? Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should give an example of what you are doing and the error report or the method code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need a binary, you might consider term_to_binary() and binary_to_term() functions..

Comment: That's great but, apparently the library I'm using actually expects a binary string. <<"record">>

Comment: Nope, you were right. The problem was mine. Thank you!